# Why is dataproc outputting an unexpected value?

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-dataproc

I have created a jar file that uses hadoop to counts the number of bigrams found in a set of text files.

When I run a hadoop job on my local setup I receive an output fie containing a count of bigrams in the text file.
[Correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWp8R.png)

however, when I use the exact same jar file but using dataproc on Google cloud platform. It outputs the following
[dataproc, incorrect output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl1Z9.png)

Any ideas why this may be happening? Cheers